# VLC: How to Create a Genuine MP4 (not M4V) File?

Tags: macos, mp4, vlc, m4v

At "File -> Convert/Stream" menu item, applying "Video - H.264 + mp3 (mp4)" profile will result in a file in m4v format instead of mp4!

Now, changing the extension from m4v to mp4 will work on some devices, while others the audio will be corrupted.

Is there a way to produce a genuine mp4 format file from VLC? If not how to reliably convert m4v into mp4?

Answer (score 17):

1. File -> Convert/Stream...
2. "Open media..." and select the file you want to convert
3. Choose the default profile "Video - H.264 + MP3 (MP4)"
4. Customize the profile with:

   1. Video codec H.264 with bitrate 768
   2. Audio codec Mpeg 4 Audio (AAC)
5. Apply the new configuration and save the file with ",m4v" extension
6. Convert the file
7. Optionally, you can now rename the file with an ".mp4" extension.

Comment: Do think you _have to_ rename the extension to mp4. This so the browser or other software can recognize the format by extension.

Comment: it could be, depending on how naive is the implementation of the browser or other software. Smart software should be able to recognize the m4v extension as well

Comment: Rename the extension only works when you use it with a desktop player (if it supports m4v). When uploading the file, if the website doesn't support m4v, it won't work. Because technically, it is still an m4v file

Answer (score -3):

When applying "Video - H.264 + mp3 (mp4)" profile make sure you tick "Keep original audio track" box under Audio codec tap. Then rename the output extension from m4v to mp4.

It should now work as a normal mp4 on different devices.

Comment: `You cannot save this document with extension ".mp4" at the end of the name. The required extension is ".m4v" `